# Want to output exact value from the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm making e-shop and i want to output the exact amount written in input field

```
  <input type="number" id="val" value="1" class="input-text" >

  $("input[type=number]").ready(function(){
    var val = $("#val").val();
    alert("there are " + val + "in your cart");
  });
```

now the problem is here that it's returning only 1 because i set the value to 1

here is fiddle example  https://jsfiddle.net/s81g6963/3/

i want the user to input value and i want that value to be multiply with the product price $9.99

Comment: Use change event https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/kbhw7oxf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `ready` on anything but the `document` element, and only in those cases where you need to wait for the DOM to be ready (perhaps because you don't control where script tags go; if you do, just put the script tag at the end of the page, before the closing `</body>` tag).

If you want that code to run when the user changes the value, use `change`:

```
$("input[type=number]").on("change", function(){
  var val = $("#val").val();
  alert("there are " + val + "in your cart");
});
```

If you want to run it *both* when the document is ready *and* when the user changes the value, put the code in a named function and use it in both places:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function useTheValue() {
      var val = $("#val").val();
      alert("there are " + val + "in your cart");
    }
    $("input[type=number]").on("change", useTheValue);
    useTheValue();
});
```

Or if the script is at the end of `body`, you can leave out the `ready`:

```
(function() {
    function useTheValue() {
      var val = $("#val").val();
      alert("there are " + val + "in your cart");
    }
    $("input[type=number]").on("change", useTheValue);
    useTheValue();
})();
```

Comment: `$("input[type=number]").on("change", function(){ ..}).trigger('change');` would also do instead of named function

Comment: @Satpal: I don't believe in triggering fake events to run functions, and so I don't promote it. Events are *inputs* into your code (in this case); if you need to call a function in your code, you should call it, not ask jQuery and the browser to. Events are useful for disconnected things, but using them to call specific functions is just an abuse (in my view).